# jQuery - Increase/Decrease value of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
            <ul class="deposit" style="float:left;list-style-type:none;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="inc"><li class="first">+</li></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dec"><li class="second">-</li></a>
            </ul>

<div class="left deposit_amount">$<span id="amountSpan"></span></div>
```

I want to do, so whenever I click the #inc the #amountSpan will increase by 5. And whenever the #dec is clicked, the value will be decreased by 5. 
I also wish to have, so the value cannot go below 0.

Currently I have this:

```
  $(function(){
    $("#inc").click(function(){
      $("#amountSpan").val( Number($("#amountSpan").val()) + 5 );
    });
    $("#dec").click(function(){
      $("#amountSpan").val( Number($("#amountSpan").val()) - 5 );
    });
  });
```

But this does not work. How can I obtain this?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I try to set a max number, with this:

```
$("#inc").click(function(){
  $("#amountSpan").text( Math.max(20, Number($("#amountSpan").text()) + 5) ) 
});
```

But it just goes past 20.

Comment: When you're trying to control the *maximum* value, you have to use `Math.min()`.  I get that backwards all the time.  So in your "inc" routine it should be `Math.min(20, Number ...)` to make sure the value is the smaller of 20 and whatever the sum is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `.val()` (which is for form input elements), use `.text()`. Oh, and when you're incrementing, you'll need to make sure the value is forced to be a number first. (oh wait you already are :-)

```
$(function(){
    $("#inc").click(function(){
      $("#amountSpan").text( Number($("#amountSpan").text()) + 5 );
    });
    $("#dec").click(function(){
      $("#amountSpan").text( Number($("#amountSpan").text()) - 5 );
    });
  });
```

To keep the amount greater than or equal to zero:

```
    $("#amountSpan").text( Math.max(0, Number($("#amountSpan").text()) - 5) )
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Dumb of me.
But how can I do, so the value/text cannot go below 0? (When decreasing)

Comment: Ah well just add a test or use `Math.max()` ... I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks! Although the math.Max you provided did not work. I can still go below zero.

Comment: Really?  That doesn't make a lot of sense ...  you're doing that in the "dec" handler right? `Math.max(0, -5)` returns `0` for me ...

Comment: Stupid me. I didn't add in the #dec handler.. Sorry. It works great now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question though. I am trying to set a max number on the "#inc". Though I thought it would be the same method, it's not working. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

for date also you can in year as per below example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increment1(myInput) {

        myInput.value = Math.min(31, (+myInput.value + 1) || 0);
    }
    function decrement1(myInput) {
        myInput.value = Math.max(1, (myInput.value - 1) || 0);
    }
    /*myInput.value = (myInput.value - 1) || 0;*/

</script>

<img src="Icalorieimage/account/increase_menu.png"
     width="25" height="20" id="target" style="float:left; cursor:pointer;" align="left"
     onclick="increment(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);"/>
<img src="Icalorieimage/account/decrease_menu.png" width="25" height="20" style="float:left; cursor:pointer;"
     align="left"
     onclick="decrement(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);"/>
```